# html <select> tag IE 7, 8 problem

Tags: html

[alt text http://www.shrani.si/f/29/f9/1pYuai84/brez-naslova.png](http://www.shrani.si/f/29/f9/1pYuai84/brez-naslova.png)

i have  tag but when i click on it it opens from top of the page not from where i click on it.

is big

```
<select name="ctl00$cplResults$ddlFromCurrency" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cplResults$ddlFromCurrency\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_cplResults_ddlFromCurrency" class="styled">
        <option value="0">Izberi</option>
        <option value="AED ">ZDRUŽENI ARABSKI EMIRATI</option>

        <option value="AFA">AFGANISTAN  </option>
        <option value="ALL ">ALBANIJA  </option>
        <option value="ANG ">NIZOZEMSKI ANTILI</option>
        <option value="ARS ">ARGENTINA</option>
        <option value="AUD ">AVSTRALIJA</option>
        <option value="AWG ">ARUBA</option>

        <option value="BBD ">BARBADOS</option>
        <option value="BHD ">BAHRAJN  </option>
        <option value="BIF ">BURUNDI</option>
        <option value="BMD ">BERMUDI</option>
        <option value="BND ">BRUNEJ</option>
        <option value="BOB ">BOLIVIJA</option>

        <option value="BRL ">BRAZILIJA</option>
        <option value="BSD ">BAHAMI</option>
        <option value="BTN ">BUTAN</option>
        <option value="BWP ">BOCVANA</option>
        <option value="BZD ">BELIZE</option>
        <option value="CAD ">KANADA</option>

        <option value="CHF ">ŠVICA</option>
        <option value="CLP ">ČILE</option>
        <option value="CNY ">KITAJSKA</option>
        <option value="COP ">KOLUMBIJA</option>
        <option value="CRC ">KOSTARIKA</option>
        <option value="CUP ">KUBA</option>

        <option value="CVE ">ZELENORTSKI OTOKI</option>
        <option value="CYP ">CIPER</option>
        <option value="CZK ">ČEŠKA REPUBLIKA</option>
        <option value="DJF ">DŽIBUTI</option>
        <option value="DKK ">DANSKA</option>
        <option value="DOP ">DOMINIKANSKA REPUBLIKA</option>

        <option value="DZD ">ALŽIRIJA</option>
        <option value="EEK ">ESTONIJA</option>
        <option value="EGP  ">EGIPT</option>
        <option value="ETB ">ETIOPIJE</option>
        <option value="EUR ">EUROPA</option>
        <option value="FKP ">FALKLANDSKI OTOKI</option>

        <option value="GBP ">VB</option>
        <option value="GHC ">GANA</option>
        <option value="GIP ">GIBRALTAR</option>
        <option value="GMD ">GAMBIJA</option>
        <option value="GNF ">GVINEJA</option>
        <option value="GTQ ">GVATEMALA</option>

        <option value="GYD ">GVAJANA</option>
        <option value="HKD ">HONGKONG</option>
        <option value="HNL ">HONDURAS</option>
        <option value="HRK ">HRVAŠKA</option>
        <option value="HTG ">HAITI</option>
        <option value="HUF ">MADŽARSKA</option>

        <option value="IDR ">INDONEZIJA</option>
        <option value="INR ">INDIJA</option>
        <option value="ISK ">ISLANDIJA</option>
        <option value="JMD ">JAMAJKA</option>
        <option value="JOD ">JORDANIJA</option>
        <option value="JPY ">JAPONSKA</option>

        <option value="KES ">KENIJA</option>
        <option value="KHR ">KAMBODŽA</option>
        <option value="KMF ">KOMORI</option>
        <option value="KPW ">SEVERNA KOREJA</option>
        <option value="KRW ">KOREJA</option>
        <option value="KWD ">KUVAJT</option>

        <option value="KYD ">KAJMANSKI OTOKI</option>
        <option value="KZT ">KAZAHSTAN</option>
        <option value="LAK ">LAOŠKA R.  </option>
        <option value="LBP ">LIBANON</option>
        <option value="LKR ">ŠRILANKA</option>
        <option value="LRD ">LIBERIJA</option>

        <option value="LSL ">LESOTO</option>
        <option value="LTL ">LITVA</option>
        <option value="LYD ">LIBIJA</option>
        <option value="MAD ">ZAHODNA SAHARA</option>
        <option value="MDL ">MOLDAVIJA</option>
        <option value="MKD ">MAKEDONIJA</option>

        <option value="MMK ">MJANMAR</option>
        <option value="MNT ">MONGOLIJA</option>
        <option value="MOP ">MACAU</option>
        <option value="MRO ">MAVRETANIJA</option>
        <option value="MUR ">MAURITIUS</option>
        <option value="MVR ">MALDIVI</option>

        <option value="MWK ">MALAVI</option>
        <option value="MXN ">MEHIKA</option>
        <option value="MYR ">MALEZIJA</option>
        <option value="MZM ">MOZAMBIK</option>
        <option value="NAD ">NAMIBIJA</option>
        <option value="NIO ">NIKARAGVA</option>

        <option value="NOK ">NORVEŠKA  </option>
        <option value="NPR ">NEPAL</option>
        <option value="NZD ">ZELANDIJA</option>
        <option value="OMR ">OMAN</option>
        <option value="PAB ">PANAMA</option>
        <option value="PEN ">PERU</option>

        <option value="PGK ">PAPUA NOVA GVINEJA</option>
        <option value="PHP ">FILIPINI</option>
        <option value="PKR ">PAKISTAN</option>
        <option value="PLN ">POLJSKA</option>
        <option value="PYG ">PARAGVAJ</option>
        <option value="QAR ">KATAR</option>

        <option value="RUB ">RUSKA FEDERACIJA</option>
        <option value="SAR ">SAUDOVA ARABIJA</option>
        <option value="SBD ">SOLOMONOVI OTOKI</option>
        <option value="SCR ">SEJŠELI</option>
        <option value="SEK">ŠVEDSKA</option>
        <option value="SGD ">SINGAPUR</option>

        <option value="SHP ">SAINT HELENA</option>
        <option value="SIT ">SLOVENIJA</option>
        <option value="SLL ">SIERRA LEONE</option>
        <option value="SOS ">SOMALIJA</option>
        <option value="STD ">SAO TOME IN PRINCIPE</option>
        <option value="SVC ">SALVADOR</option>

        <option value="SYP ">SIRIJA</option>
        <option value="SZL ">SVAZI</option>
        <option value="THB ">TAJSKA</option>
        <option value="TND ">TUNIZIJA</option>
        <option value="TOP ">TONGA</option>
        <option value="TRL ">TURČIJA-LIRA</option>

        <option value="TRY ">TURČIJA</option>
        <option value="TTD ">TRINIDAD IN TOBAGO</option>
        <option value="TWD ">TAJVAN</option>
        <option value="TZS ">TANZANIJA</option>
        <option value="UAH ">UKRAJINA</option>
        <option value="UGX ">UGANDA</option>

        <option value="USD ">ZDA  </option>
        <option value="UYU ">URUGVAJ</option>
        <option value="VEB ">VENEZUELA</option>
        <option value="VND ">VIETNAM</option>
        <option value="VUV ">VANUATU</option>
        <option value="WST ">SAMOA</option>

        <option value="XAF ">SREDNJEAFRIŠKA REPUBLIKA</option>
        <option value="XCD ">SAINT VINCENT IN GRENADINE</option>
        <option value="XOF ">TOGO</option>
        <option value="XPF ">NOVA KALEDONIJA</option>
        <option value="YER ">JEMEN</option>
        <option value="ZAR ">JUŽNA AFRIKA</option>

        <option value="ZMK ">ZAMBIJA</option>
        <option value="ZWD ">ZIMBAVE</option>

    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think can't,
try to use font-size to  crontrol?

```
<select style="font-size:7px;">
..
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not controllable. You can try to use "size" attribute, but it will give you different appearance of select-box.

Answer (score 1):

you can't crontrol that. this behavior depends on OS and browser.